# Check substring match of a word in a list of words

Tags: python, substring, string-matching

I want to check if a word is in a list of words.

```
word = "with"
word_list = ["without", "bla", "foo", "bar"]
```

I tried `if word in set(list)`, but it is not yielding the wanted result due to the fact `in` is matching string rather than item. That is to say, `"with"` is a match in any of the words in the `word_list` but still `if "with" in set(list)` will say `True`.

What is a simpler way for doing this check than manually iterate over the `list`?

Comment: What results would you want then?

Comment: Are you really using the name `list` to store that list, or is it just for illustration?  It's a builtin, so you should avoid using names that would obscure it.

Comment: Good point Brian! In any case it is a good idea to avoid overriding list keyword

Comment: ... But `"with"` **isn't** in that list, per the definitions that programmers normally find useful.

Comment: oh yeah, I think I get a formulation of the problem now.

Comment: Do you want the **first** match? **any** match? **all** matches? (list or set) What result should it give if *`word_list = ["without", "withering", "withhold", "forthwith", ...]`*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do:

```
found = any(word in item for item in wordlist)
```

It checks each word for a match and returns true if any are matches

Comment: Ok no doubts now. This is a brilliant solution!

Comment: It doesn't check *each* word if there is a match it returns (short-circuit) immediately after the first match.

Comment: That is true. For me, it is unclear whether he is looking for a boolean result or a full list of matches.

Answer (score 3):

`in` is working as expected for an **exact match**:

```
>>> word = "with"
>>> mylist = ["without", "bla", "foo", "bar"]
>>> word in mylist
False
>>>
```

You can also use:

```
milist.index(myword)  # gives error if your word is not in the list (use in a try/except)
```

or

```
milist.count(myword)  # gives a number > 0 if the word is in the list.
```

However, if you are looking for a **substring**, then:

```
for item in mylist:
    if word in item:     
        print 'found'
        break
```

btw, dont use `list` for the name of a variable

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a single search string by concatenating all of the words in word_list into a single string:

```
word = "with" 
word_list = ' '.join(["without", "bla", "foo", "bar"])
```

Then a simple `in` test will do the job:

```
return word in word_list
```